# Angular RouteProvider, returning a certain template depending on routeParams

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I'd like to achieve something like:

```
.when('/event/group/:gid', {
            if($routeParams.gid == 124){
                controller: 'ACtrl',
                templateUrl: '/event/A/foo.html'
            } else {
                controller: 'BCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/event/B/bar.html'
            }
        })
```

So literally I would like to use a route parameter as a condition to decide which controller and view to render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be dome by returning a function on your templateUrl.

```
.when('/event/group/:gid', {
    controller: 'ACtrl',
    templateUrl: function (params) {
        if(params.gid == 124){
           return '/event/A/foo.html'
        } else {
           return '/event/B/bar.html'
        }
     }
  });
```

Comment: Thxs ! However I realized part of my problem was that params are sent in the shape of `?gid={{group.id}}` which doesn't match the params `:gid` in angular route. Any idea on how I can get this query in my route ?

Comment: You can set the link using `ngHref=event/group//{{group.id}}`

Comment: Yes, but the thing is all route query parameters have been written in the shape of `?key=value`, so I'd rather change my route instead of changing all my href :)

Comment: Since you're using query parameters instead of actual routing, you might want to look into directives.